# rails find_by sql injection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection

So I know that Rails helps protect against sql injections when used like this:

```
Object.find(:first, :conditions=>["name=?",name])
```

However, I can't seem to find if the autogenerated find_by and find_all_by methods protect agains sql injection.

i.e:

```
Object.find_by_name(name)
```

So these two calls have the exact same result. My question is even though the second one is more convenient, should I continue to use the first because it provides protection against sql injection, or does the second do that as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, dynamic attribute-based finders (`find_by_*` family) **do** protect your app from sql injections.

Comment: so using where is better than using find?

Comment: I withdrew that point as highly subjective. I just like it more. :)